# Web application create Excel like grid and store in database

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript, php, microsoft-excel

Web application create Excel like grid and store in database

I'm looking at a project that will emulate the functions of a Excel worksheet so that an end user can specify cells and headings and what types of data each cell will hold (text, interger, float, date).

Once the worksheet is defined, it should be possible to display it using values contained in a database, and edit those values.

It will not just be a simple 5 column by 10 rows design (for example), but have a mixture of boxes relating to a sub set of data, see screen grab of a sample current Excel file in use.

This is for web application and the server side will be PHP/MySQL running on Apache/Unix.

Open source or commercial solutions welcome, thanks!

[image: Sample spreadsheet]